# 'RetryPolicy' an ambiguous reference

Tags: azure

I get this error:

```
'RetryPolicy' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.RetryPolicy'
```

I wonder where is the redundancy, does StorageClient now include Retry abilities?

Comment: "Does StorageClient now include..." Now, and since 2008, IIRC, though I think they were revamped in early 2009. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Windows Azure Storage client libraries does include Retry policies specific functionalities  built into and can be used by referencing as appropriate. The RetryPolicies in the Storage Client Library are used to allow the users to customize the retry behavior when and exception occurs.

With reference to Windows Azure Storage, the details about retry policies are described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/03/overview-of-retry-policies-in-the-windows-azure-storage-client-library.aspx) with source multiple case scenarios and code examples.